# Разница между функциями wsprintfW() и swprintf_s()

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Собственно не могу понять в чем же разница между 2мя этими функциями, когда они дают идентичные результаты.

```
wsprintfW()
```

и

```
swprintf_s()
```

Стало очень интересно, но где-то видел что `wsprintfW()` не может работать с типами `float` и `double` правда ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совcем. [`swprintf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) принимает дополнительные параметры, а именно `sizeOfBuffer`, задающий максимально допустимую длину данных в выходном буфере. Так что его можно считать Unicode-вариантом [`vsprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/),